# How to extract the information from tab delimited large file using awk in the following way?

Tags: perl, sed, awk

**input**

```
a  1   20
   4   50
b  5   20
   2   90
r  5   70
```

now i want to retrieve the information >=50 from the 3rd column and its respective letter of 1st column.

**output**

```
a  4  50
b  2  90
r  5  70
```

Comment: You said you want >50 but posted output for >=50. Please clarify.

Comment: This is really a very, very simple 'awk' question. Do you know awk? Have you tried to learn `awk`? If so, exactly what is the issue you're running into? One of the requirements is to have some knowledge of the programming language you're asking about. This can be absolutely minimal knowledge, but ***some*** knowledge is required. Here's a webpage that is about [learning AWK](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Answer (score 1):

try this one-liner (awk):

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '$1!=" "{k=$1}$NF<50{next}$1=k' file
```

with your file:

```
kent$  cat f
a   1   20
    4   50
b   5   20
    2   90
r   5   70

kent$  awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '$1!=" "{k=$1}$NF<50{next}$1=k' f
a   4   50
b   2   90
r   5   70
```

**EDIT**

```
$1!=" "{k=$1}     if $1 is not " ", assign $1 to var k
$NF<50{next}      if the last col ($NF) < 50, stop processing, read next line
$1=k              otherwise, assign k to $1, and print the line.
```

Comment: plz explain the command how it works...

Comment: which part you don't understand? does it solve your problem?

Comment: its working $1!=" "{k=$1}$NF<50{next}$1=k.... plz give a brief discription about it

Comment: I'd have thought $1 would be `""` not `" "` when not present. Surprised the OP says it's working.

Comment: @EdMorton I posted like that in the 1st version. checked `NF==3`, after that, I watched the input file for a while, I thought the absent `$1` would be replaced by a space. so I changed my mind. :)

Comment: Since it's tab-separated, there WILL be 3 fields, but the first one should be whatever's before the first tab and that SHOULD be `""` unless the input file has a literal blank character before that first tab.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
a       1       20
        4       50
b       5       20
        2       90
r       5       70

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {if ($1=="") $1=k; else k=$1} $NF>50' file
b       2       90
r       5       70

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {if ($1=="") $1=k; else k=$1} $NF>=50' file
a       4       50
b       2       90
r       5       70
```